# ?thesaurical, adj

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, is-it-a-word, derivational-morphology

The adjectival form of *thesaurus* does not seem to have been listed on (all) standard dictionaries. However, *thesaurical* occurs in literature<sup>1</sup> and is also defined in Urban Dictionary.

Do we have an alternate 'listed' word for a context like the one below (a question of the sort dealt with on the pages of thesauri)?

> But, Sir, that's a **thesaurical** question.

<sup>1</sup> *These are the next epithets theorists have up their **thesaurical** sleeves.* 
([New Scientist, 1977](http://books.google.com/books?id=fVD3Sdv0mv4C&pg=PA154&dq=thesaurical&hl=en&sa=X&ei=-6q-Ua3kBcqArgfw9oC4Dw&ved=0CEQQ6AEwBQ))

Comment: Requested tag edits please.

Comment: At http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=6280 Ken Greenwood et al cover similar murky grounds. Noncing _thesaurical_ is surely not as bad as waxing thesaurical.

Comment: I did mean *?thesaurical* -- whether the 'thesaurical' is a word.

Comment: 'Thesaurical' is used in [Text, Speech and Dialogue: Second International Workshop, TSD'99 Plzen ...](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=KDjMUX3sYmIC&pg=PA365&lpg=PA365&dq=thesaurical&source=bl&ots=Kq1KhKmrSD&sig=Vh1VtQZ4f2dszqew6HHR8YkCgq0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2FODU9_qGqqb0QWav4B4&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=thesaurical&f=false)
 edited by Vaclav Matousek. A 'universal dictionary of English' is advocated, which might be expected to contain 'thesaurical'.

Answer (score 7):

OED has

> **thesaurus** *noun*
>
> Etymology:  Latin, < Greek *θησαυρός* a store, treasure, storehouse, treasury.
>
> **1.** *Archaeol.* A treasury, as of a temple, etc.
> **2.**
>   **a.** A ‘treasury’ or ‘storehouse’ of knowledge, as a dictionary, encyclopædia, or the like.
>   **b.** A collection of concepts or words arranged according to sense; also (U.S.) a dictionary of synonyms and antonyms.
>   **c.** A classified list of terms, esp. key-words, in a particular field, for use in indexing and information retrieval.

I didn't realise the word meant *treasury*, but that leads us to

> **thesaurarial** *adjective*
>
> Etymology:  < Latin *thēsaurārius* (see **thesaurary** *n.*) + **-al** *suffix*<sup>1</sup>.
>
> Of or pertaining to the office of treasurer.
>
> †**thesaury** *noun*
>
> Cheifly *Sc. Obs.*: The treasury; the treasurership.

OED doesn't list a canonical adjective for "of or pertaining a dictionary of synonyms", but it would be possible to coin ***thesaurial*** from *thesaury* which is sufficiently like *thesaurus* to be intelligible, and which introduces neither the extra syllable of *thesaurarial* nor the *-c-* in *thesaurical*.

I guess that *New Scientist* coined *thesaurical* because of its similar sound to *rhetorical*, but that is to misuse the *-ical* ending. The base word does not end *-ic*.

Comment: I had never connected the Italian word, tesoro (treasure), with thesaurus but it does make a lot of sense. Thank you for that gold nugget!

Comment: Great find. However, the context I stated does not related to 'treasury' as you can see. Thanks all the same.